# C# Combo Box Not responsive after values have been added

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, ftp

I am trying to add items to a combobox from an ftp server and then based on the value selected use that to populate other comboboxes. This works for only two of my values. this is the code for added the items to the combo box.

```
 private string FTP_SERVER()
    {
      string result = string.Empty;
      //Request location and server name---------->
       FtpWebRequest request = 
      (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://********.com" +"/" + "Products" + 
                                                                        "/");
        //Lists directory
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        // set credentials
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1","1234");//request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(" ", " ");
        //initiaze response
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //reader to read response
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        //data from file.
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();


     //Adds to drop down box for updates.
     //This is the loop that is looking through the items and adding them to the Combo box.    

     string[] y = result.Split('\n');
      foreach (string x in y)
      {
         string files = x;
         DropBox.Items.Add(files);   
      }

       response.Close();
       return result;
    }
```

this is the code that i am using to see what has been selected to know how to populate the other combo boxes. The problem is that when I select a value form the text box and hit submit. It does not recognize it as a value added.

```
if (DropBox.Text == "thing1.txt") //If choose 
  Macchiato
{
  if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to check for 
                 updates for this product?", "Confirm",              
                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == 
                  DialogResult.Yes)
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance!
I just do not understand why it is not seeing it as a value. I click submit and the combo box goes blank and nothing happens. It should show a message box. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for saying that, but your code is really just a miss. Try organize it and wirte the [Minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can. Why are you closing the response later ? what is the `return` in your code ?

Comment: You should also tag what UI framework you are using (e.g. WPF, Winforms or UWP)

Comment: It is returning the values from the ftp server. They are text files. I am sorry for this mess. I am a student and working on a project

Comment: this is windows forms

Comment: You keep asking new questions, without giving any feedback to answers you got to your previous questions.

Comment: This is a debugging problem.  Put a debug stop on your code and step through it line by line and watch the variables.

Comment: "The problem is that when I select a value form the text box and hit submit" what do you mean by selecting a value from text box?

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good idea check the Text of your dropbox, why not use selectedvalue?

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Pippo"
```

(or even better use string.Equals)

Comment: In C# there's no (practical) difference (for strings)  between `==` and `string.equals` as long as they are typed as `string.` But when using an `object` for example or `Generics`  methods,  you definitely want to use the `Equals` method.